# I hope to display empty day to 0 in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I use line / area chart to display datetime data.
see example : http://jsfiddle.net/YFERb/

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 106.4],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 5), 75],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 129.2],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 10), 176.0]
             ]
        }]

    });
});
```

But I want to fill empty day to 0.
see example : http://jsfiddle.net/RSPNU/

so below day is filled 0.
2010.0.2,
2010.0.4, 
2010.0.7,
2010.0.8,
2010.0.9

I insert 0 in empty day.
But it is very heavy.

So I want to display like 2nd example except inserting 0 or null data.

If you have other way, please reply this.
thank you.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question, but I'll give you some answer. Lets see if it helps. :)

Comment: @Ricardo-lohmann. I want to display 0 excepting insert 0

Answer (score 1):

To avoid points you can set it's value to `null`.
When you do it your chart will have a gap between null points, so you have to set `connectNulls` to `true`.

```
series: [{
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), null],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 106.4],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 4), null],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 5), 75],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 129.2],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), null],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8), null],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 9), null],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 10), 176.0]
     ]
}],

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        connectNulls: true
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/RSPNU/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to display except inserting empty data. I think your answer is similar with my way(jsfiddle.net/RSPNU). It's too heavy.

Answer (score 1):

In general, how Highcharts should know that you want to put 0 every day, not every hour, or maybe every second? If you know how is your data cropped you can set `pointInterval` and `pointStart` for a series. Then you can update each of the points which should have different value, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/YFERb/3/